# How to convert "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" into readable format Using Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, powershell-2.0

Have written a custom PowerShell script to retrieve azure ad conditional access policies information and save the output in a csv file. I'm using `Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy cmdlet queries to achieve that`.

Some of `Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy` cmdlet parameter values is returning `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] `` values, i need this information in a readable format or at least `none` if the value for the parameter is empty.

Below is my script:

```
$allpolicies = Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy 

$allpolicies | ForEach-Object{

    $policyID = $_.Id
    $policydisplayname = $_.DisplayName
    $policystate = $_.State
    $applications = ($_.Conditions).Applications.IncludeApplications
    $includedusers = ($_.Conditions).Users.IncludeUsers
    $includedgroups = ($_.Conditions).Users.IncludeGroups
    $includedlocation = ($_.Conditions).Locations.includelocations


    New-object -typename PSobject -property @{

        ID = $policyID
        DisplayName = $policydisplayname
        Policy_State = $policystate
        Includedapps =  $applications
        Users_Applied_The_Policy = $includedusers
        Groups_Applied_The_Policy = $includedgroups
        Locations_Applied_The_Policy = $includedlocation


    }

} | Sort-Object ID, DisplayName, Policy_State, Includedapps, Users_Applied_Policy, Groups_Applied_Policy, Locations_Applied | Export-Csv -Path C:\CAccessResults3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Output in the csv file;
[image]

On running the script without saving information into a csv file, the results is different, below is the snipshot.

[image]

I'm expecting to have the csv file have readable information for `Includedapps, Users_Applied_Policy, Groups_Applied_Policy, Locations_Applied` parameters.

Comment: How do you want to format/separate the individual values in each list? `app1;app2;app3`?

Comment: Yeah, that format, or is it possible to have  each app appear in a separate row, even if it belongs to the same policy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either turn the lists into strings with the `-join` operator:

```
$allpolicies = Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy 

$allpolicies | ForEach-Object {
    New-object -typename PSobject -property @{
        ID                           = $_.Id
        DisplayName                  = $_.DisplayName
        Policy_State                 = $_.State
        Includedapps                 = ($_.Conditions).Applications.IncludeApplications -join ';'
        Users_Applied_The_Policy     = ($_.Conditions).Users.IncludeUsers -join ';'
        Groups_Applied_The_Policy    = ($_.Conditions).Users.IncludeGroups -join ';'
        Locations_Applied_The_Policy = ($_.Conditions).Locations.includelocations -join ';'
    }
} | Sort-Object ID, DisplayName, Policy_State, Includedapps, Users_Applied_Policy, Groups_Applied_Policy, Locations_Applied | Export-Csv -Path C:\CAccessResults3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Or you can output one object *per conditional target* (1 object = 1 row):

```
$allpolicies = Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy 

$allpolicies | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($application in ($_.Conditions).Applications.IncludeApplications){
        New-object -typename PSobject -property @{
            ID                           = $_.Id
            DisplayName                  = $_.DisplayName
            Policy_State                 = $_.State
            TargetType                   = 'Application'
            TargetName                   = $application
        }
    }

    foreach($user in ($_.Conditions).Users.IncludeUsers){
        New-object -typename PSobject -property @{
            ID                           = $_.Id
            DisplayName                  = $_.DisplayName
            Policy_State                 = $_.State
            TargetType                   = 'User'
            TargetName                   = $user
        }
    }

    foreach($group in ($_.Conditions).Users.IncludeGroups){
        New-object -typename PSobject -property @{
            ID                           = $_.Id
            DisplayName                  = $_.DisplayName
            Policy_State                 = $_.State
            TargetType                   = 'Group'
            TargetName                   = $group
        }
    }

    foreach($location in ($_.Conditions).Locations.includelocations){
        New-object -typename PSobject -property @{
            ID                           = $_.Id
            DisplayName                  = $_.DisplayName
            Policy_State                 = $_.State
            TargetType                   = 'Location'
            TargetName                   = $location
        }
    }
} | Sort-Object ID, DisplayName, TargetType, TargetName | Export-Csv -Path C:\CAccessResults3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias, this works fine for me, however is there a way to translate the GUID of the user applied the policy to actual display name or UPN?

Comment: @Bernietechy I don't have much experience with the azure cmdlets, but I'd assume you can do something like replacing `TargetName = $user` with `TargetName = (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $user).UserPrincipalName`