# Powershell 7 - Get-AzureADUser, AssignedLicenses, Convert Class to Object

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, powershell-core

When I retieve an AzureADUser while using the AzureAD module (imported with -UseWindowsPowershell), and trying to retrieve the property for AssignedLicenses, they return as a Class instead of an obect (e.g. just a string?)

```
class AssignedLicense {
  DisabledPlans: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
  SkuId: zzzzzzzz-2c81-4ef7-yyyy-5b5392b571df}


class AssignedLicense {
  DisabledPlans: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
  SkuId: zzzzzzz-fae0-4ca2-xxxx-7a907fd6c235
}
```

How would I convert such a thing to something I can actually use (e.g. an object?)

At first I thought it was JSON, but the ConvertFrom-JSON cmdlet gave errors on the notation, as far as I am aware there is no ConvertFrom-Class included in normal powershell :)

Did also try to just remove all the text and keep anything after SkuID, but that proves a challenge when the DisabledPlans is bigger/smaller than I expect.

Output received by running these commands:

```
$userList = Get-AzureADUser -filter "AccountEnabled eq true"
foreach ($u in $userList) {
    $Assigned = ($u | Select-Object AssignedLicenses).AssignedLicenses
}
```

Comment: Could you please help us with the command you tried in PowerShell, thanks

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the scenario in my environment***:

I tried the same script as yours:

```
$userList = Get-AzureADUser -filter "AccountEnabled eq true"
foreach ($u in $userList) {
    $Assigned =($u | Select-Object AssignedLicenses ).AssignedLicenses 
    $Assigned 
}
```

Getting expected result :

[image]

Alternately I tried with below commands:

```
$users = Get-AzureADUser -filter "AccountEnabled eq true" 

$users | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($user in $_.AssignedLicenses){
        New-object -typename PSobject -property @{
            ID                           = $_.Id
            DisplayName                  = $_.DisplayName
            DisabledPlans                = $user.DisabledPlans
            SkuId                        = $user.SkuId

        }
    }} | Sort-Object ID, DisplayName, DisabledPlans, SkuId | Export-Csv -Path C:\Assignedlicense2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I am getting the same result type  for disabled plans `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]` as below image:

- You can try the second way and check from your end  or adding `-join` parameter to each object .

**Reference:** [powershell - How to convert "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" into readable format Using Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy cmdlet - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71337518/how-to-convert-system-collections-generic-list1system-string-into-readable)

[image]

Or directly use:

```
$userList = Get-AzureADUser -filter "AccountEnabled eq true"
foreach ($u in $userList) {
    $Assigned =$u.AssignedLicenses 
    $Assigned 
}
```

Comment: Hey kavya Saraboju -- Thank you for your answer, I think the difference between our enviroments is that I am using Powershell 7 (core), When I use ISE (which uses PS5) I get the same expected output. I feel like this is more of an issue with PS7+AzureADModule than it is with the actual command. Just wondering if there is a way I can transform such a response myself.

Comment: I am currently actively transforming all scripts to use PS7, and stopped using ISE because of that (it's all deprecated/announced deprecation), In fact, the AzureAD-Module is also being deprecated soon, so I've already started transitioning to mgGraph.. however, for learning purposes I would like to know how I can convert such a returned "class"- to something usable

Comment: Have you got a chance to check with -join  something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71337518/how-to-convert-system-collections-generic-list1system-string-into-readable)